# How to use Azure's Encryption at Rest via REST API

Tags: rest, azure, encryption, azure-virtual-machine

I've found documentation for applying Encryption at Rest using PowerShell, the CLI, and json templates.  However...

How do I achieve this strictly using the **Azure REST API**?

Thank you.

(Desired end result is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-encryption-atrest)

(PowerShell method is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-disk-encryption)

Comment: What are you encrypting, VM disks, or blobs in blob storage? For the latter, you enable it and then its transparent: "customers using Azure blob storage can enable encryption at rest on each Azure storage resource account. Once enabled server-side encryption is done transparently to the application."   Are you looking for a way to _enable_ it via the REST API?

Comment: VM disks, in this case.  Encryption at rest at a disk's creation, and enabling encryption at rest on an unencrypted disk already running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encryption OS disk with the [rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-create-or-update).

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vm}&api-version={apiVersion}
```

In request body json, you need add below:

```
  "encryptionSettings": {
          "enabled": true,
          "diskEncryptionKey": {
            "sourceVault": {
              "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{vaultName}"
            },
            "secretUrl": "https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/{secret-name}/{secret-version}"
          },
          "keyEncryptionKey": {
            "sourceVault": {
              "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{vaultName}"
            },
            "keyUrl": "https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/keys/{key-name}/{key-version}"
          }
```

You also encryption managed disk, please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/manageddisks/disks/disks-create-or-update).

Comment: `and enabling encryption at rest on an unencrypted disk already running`. I also don't see what api could do this. Maybe you could use java SDK to do this. See this link https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/pull/1466